# CentOS 8 Installer not detecting the internal SSD

Tags: centos, system-installation, ssd

I have a 256 GB SSD in my laptop with Windows 10 as an OS. I want to install CentOS 8 for a dual boot setup, but the problem is that the CentOS setup could not detect my hard disk. The SATA SSD uses the AHCI controller and everything is okay, but I still have the problem. I hope someone can help me?

Comment: CentOS 8 contains a relatively old kernel which might not support your hardware. Please try installing Fedora 32 instead.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Maybe he doesn't want to use Fedora 32. Instead of suggesting that he install another OS, it's better to help him find out why the SSD isn't being detected such as getting information on the SSD and the Windows installation and also, the laptop itself.

Comment: Does the SSD have unallocated space or does it have all of the partitions with NTFS as the filesystem?

Comment: @NasirRiley He specifically said *CentOS setup could not detect my hard disk*, not partitions. Also, while you're so great at giving advice, please tell us how an experienced user can approach this issue. I know how but it involves a very deep understanding of Linux, command line utilities, kernel and package management. Yes, it's possible to rebuild the installation media with a custom fresh kernel but even in this case such a configuration is neither supported, nor recommended to use.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov There's no need to take things so personally and throw a tantrum. If all of the partitions on the hard disk have NTFS partitions, then the CentOS installer won't see it. I have given several answers here to questions just like this where the installer wasn't seeing a disk that had Windows installed on it and after asking, the OP confirmed that the disk was using NTFS, and after advising them to delete the partition and leave it as unallocated space, the installer recognized it and they were able to proceed with the installation.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov The CentOS 8 kernel is new enough to see even the latest hardware including storage devices. In the case that it just happens that it isn't, it's best to confirm this find out what he's using, how things are set up, and what he's doing before jumping the gun and telling him to use a different operating system. That's how an experienced user would approach it instead of just concluding that the kernel is too old without trying anything else.

Comment: And here on Stack Exchange at least four people have upgraded their CentOS 8 kernel to the current stable release and have had their issues resolved, so I just stuck to the OP statement where he said that the installer doesn't see the disk at all. I will now fire up a VM and test your theory about NTFS formatted disk with no free space.

Comment: Well, just like I thought, CentOS sees the disk perfectly: https://imgur.com/gallery/4eL941S

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov You are using a virtual hard disk whereas the OP is using a physical hard disk in a laptop. Perhaps the CentOS installer sees it in your case there but until we have more information on his case, there's no way of knowing whether it has to do with the kernel which is why it doesn't make sense to state that it does and he should install Fedora. Did you ever consider verifying that beforehand or that maybe Fedora isn't an option and that he needs CentOS for what he's doing? Without more details, there's no way to know if it has anything to do with the kernel.

Comment: What version CentOS 8 are you trying to install? What is the model of the laptop? Have you attempted to install any other Linux distros on it?

Comment: *What version CentOS 8 are you trying to install?* - there's just one version.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov No, there isn't. Do you not understand that there are several minor releases for each?

Comment: At every mirror, `N` points to the latest available release, e.g. for `8` https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/centos/8 -> `8.2.2004`. It's highly unlikely the user downloaded something different. The same goes for the official download page: https://www.centos.org/download/